# Can't load an Image using <Image/> tag in NextJs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, nextjs-image

okay I am using this code in nextJs 13 and can't load the Image :

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
const Profile = () => {
  const src =
    "https://secure.internxt.com/sh/file/0a00cdcc3be94569cd4c/a757e449135f3d4308549168333bf69294dfcf23fa81a402a85bd2f0501bd62e";
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Image
          src={src}
          width={30}
          height={30}
          alt="loading"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

and I have also changed the next.config.js and restarted the server but still does not work :

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "secure.internxt.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "localhost:3000/Profile",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I have used the legacy way of providing the link in the next.config.js file, and still pages comes up but the photo does not load.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images : {
    domains : ["secure.internxt.com"]
  }
}
  
module.exports = nextConfig
```